# How to write NSFetchRequest with multiple sort descriptors?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a `Student` Entity which has a `dateOfBirth` attribute.

I want to fetch all Students from the `Student` Entity in ascending order of their date fo birth but grouped by the decending order of the month.

for example: students which belong to the same Month are grouped together in ascending order but all the groups are in descending order.

> Section 1: December 2019
>   -- student 1: DOB - 1 December 2019
>   -- student 2: DOB - 2 December 2019
>   -- student 3: DOB - 3 December 2019
>   Section 2: November 2019
>   -- student 1: DOB - 1 November 2019
>   -- student 2: DOB - 2 November 2019
>   -- student 3: DOB - 3 November 2019
>   Section 3: October 2019
>   -- student 1: DOB - 1 October 2019
>   -- student 2: DOB - 2 October 2019
>   -- student 3: DOB - 3 October 2019

Is it possible to write a `NSFetchRequest` to support this query? I have to use `NSFetchResultsController` to populate `UITableView` but I am unable to write a fetch request.

To group the students by their `dateOfBirth` I have an extra attribute which is a `yearMonthString` with dateFormat `yyyyMM`. I am using `yearMonthString` attribute to group students.

```swift
let studentFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Student> = Student.fetchRequest()
studentFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K != nil AND %K != nil", #keyPath(Student.dateOfBirth), #keyPath(Student.yearMonthString))

let dateSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Student.dateOfBirth), ascending: false)
studentFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSortDescriptor]

let frc = NSFetchedResultsController<Student>(fetchRequest: studentFetchRequest,
                                              managedObjectContext: managedContext,
                                              sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Student.yearMonthString),
                                              cacheName: nil)
```

If I give `dateSortDescriptor` as ascending then all section also become ascending and if I give `dateSortDescriptor` as descending then students within the section becomes descending.

What is the correct way to write this fetch request? Is it possible to give different sort descriptor for the sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two sort descriptors, one to sort by the year/month (descending), then another to sort by date of birth (ascending):

```
let groupSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Student.yearMonthString), ascending: false)
let dateSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Student.dateOfBirth), ascending: true)
studentFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [groupSortDescriptor, dateSortDescriptor]
```